# Queue connect issue. QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str). The MAC signature... not the same as any computed signature

Tags: azure-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to follow the Microsoft queue quickstart [that can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-quickstart-queues-python?tabs=connection-string%2Croles-azure-portal%2Cenvironment-variable-windows%2Csign-in-azure-cli)

Since I get an error creating a queue, I am attempting to use this method:

```
connect_str = "<my connection string from portal>"
QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

# List all queues in the storage account
all_queues = queue_service_client.list_queues()
```

I am using the connection string because my org does not use managed identities yet, so that is not an option.

Of course I really need to do "all the things" with queues but since that gave me trouble I tried just listing queues on that storage account, but to no avail. Same error whether trying to create one or list them.

Here is the error:

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request ... is not the same as any computed signature.

I have also tried using the API using the key and encoding the time but I get the same response. I used BingChat to search for similar issues. It found several "here" and other places, but none of them relate.

I know that my connection string is correct because I use it to access (read/write) specific BLOBs with no problem using the BLOB client.

I **can** access queues I know exist using the Azure CLI.

I first tried with an 11.7.x version of the SDK. Updating to 12.0.0 did not change the result.

1. I think it may be a bug but decided to start here. My impression is
   that to use the connection string method, I should not need to be
   authenticated. Is that correct?
2. I could try authenticating with the VSC sign-in but I believe I will
   need the connection string approach once I deploy to Azure. Is that
   correct?

Comment: Hi, @M T where are you fetching the `connection_string` is it from the portal?

Comment: @Venkatesan Thanks for the question. Not 100% sure how you mean fetch so: 1) Copied from portal. Started as in the Quickstart with an env var. Then just hardwired it into the code to be sure. And like I said, it's the same that I use for other storage account functions. I'd be happy to give more context if needed.

Comment: @M T, I copied `connection_string` from the portal like same as you https://i.imgur.com/YHnO3zQ.png and the code works perfectly in my environment and `list` the queues here is my code output: -https://i.imgur.com/dwmEbLF.png

Comment: @Venkatesan : so what would you suggest?

Comment: @M T, it seems like the connection string you are using is correct and should be working. Since you have already tried regenerating the account key and checking your system clock, the issue might be related to your network or firewall settings.

Comment: @Venkatesan : Good suggestions, but I haven't regenerated keys. But I tested by using the blob service client to retrieve files. Since that works, I assume the key is fine. Also, doesn't that mean it is not a firewall issue? Or are settings for queues different than other storage account functions? I have been wondering if there is some difference between auth for blob service and queues that could be causing the issue.

Comment: There is no such difference in authentication between blob and queue In my environment I can able to list  the queues with the same connection string.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots or errors you are facing so that I can able to solve the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255912/discussion-between-m-t-and-venkatesan).

Comment: @M T Can you share your connection string structure?

Comment: @Venkatesan: As copied directly from portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RequestId:5fc43cc9-9003-0074-7696-175ae6000000 Time:2023-11-15T07:39:35.9380493Z ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed authenticationerrordetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request'Uxxxxx=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET

The above error occurs If the **`connection string`** or **`account key`**  used to authenticate the request is wrong or has expired. ensure that the connection string and account key for your Azure Blob storage account are accurate. You can also try regenerating the account key and replacing it in the connection string.

Connection string be:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat678;AccountKey=<Your-storage-account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

When I tried with the same code with the correct connection string and using **`azure-storage-queue= 12.8.0`** Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient

connect_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat678;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
try:
    print("Azure Queue storage - Python quickstart sample")
    
    # Create a QueueService object which will be used to create and manipulate the queue
    queue_service = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str)
    # List all queues in the storage account
    queues = queue_service.list_queues()
    for queue in queues:
        print(queue.name)

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

**Output:**

```
Azure Queue storage - Python quickstart sample
queue1
queue2
queue3
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure Storage Queues client library for Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-queue-readme?view=azure-python#creating-the-client-from-a-connection-string)

**Update:**

You can get the connection_string from the portal also:

***Storage account-> access key -> copy the connection string.***

[image]

Comment: I felt bad downvoting you so I tried pasting in the conn string again. Somehow 15 - 20 characters in the middle got deleted. When I pasted it again, it worked! So thanks!

Comment: I can't change my down vote unless you edit. So maybe add, "Connection strings are easy to mess up. As a last resort, try copy/pasting it from the portal again. This has helped people in the past. :)

Comment: @MT Check the updated Post.